# Symfony Login Serialize/Unserialize not working, invalid string

Tags: php, symfony, serialization

I am trying to use the serialize/userialize methods as described in the Symfony documentation [here](http://symfony.com/doc/current/security/entity_provider.html#create-your-user-entity) in order to login the user.

When I dump the token inside the ContextListener and try to unserialize the string I get an error of an invalid string.

The username field is actually the email field.

> UserEntity

```
/**
 * @ORM\Table(name="users")
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="XXX\UserBundle\Repository\UserRepository")
 * @ORM\HasLifecycleCallbacks()
 * @UniqueEntity("username")
 */
class User extends AbstractEntity implements UserInterface, AdvancedUserInterface, \Serializable
{

    /**
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
     */
    protected $id;

    /**
     * @ORM\ManyToMany(
     *      targetEntity="XXX\UserBundle\Entity\UserRoles",
     *     inversedBy="users"
     * )
     * @ORM\JoinTable(
     *     name="users_user_role",
     *     joinColumns={@ORM\JoinColumn(name="user_id", referencedColumnName="id")},
     *     inverseJoinColumns={@ORM\JoinColumn(name="role_id", referencedColumnName="id")}
     * )
     */
    protected $roles;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(name="password", type="string", length=64)
     */
    protected $password;

    /**
     * @Assert\NotBlank()
     * @Assert\Length(max=4096)
     */
    protected $plainPassword;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(name="enabled", type="boolean")
     */
    protected $enabled = true;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(name="locked", type="boolean")
     */
    protected $locked = false;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(name="expired", type="boolean")
     */
    protected $expired = false;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(name="expires_at", type="datetime", nullable=true)
     */
    protected $expiresAt;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(name="last_login", type="datetime", nullable=true)
     */
    protected $lastLogin;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(name="confirmation_token", type="string")
     */
    protected $confirmationToken;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(name="password_requested_at", type="datetime", nullable=true)
     */
    protected $passwordRequestedAt;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(name="credentials_expired", type="boolean")
     */
    protected $credentialsExpired = false;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(name="user_default_language", type="string")
     */
    protected $userDefaultLanguage;

//getters and setters

public function isAccountNonExpired()
{
    return $this->getExpired();
}

public function isAccountNonLocked()
{
    return $this->getLocked();
}

public function isCredentialsNonExpired()
{
    return;
}

public function isEnabled()
{
    return $this->getEnabled();
}

/**
 * @return string
 */
public function serialize()
{
    return serialize([
        $this->id,
        $this->username,
        $this->password,
        $this->enabled,
    ]);
}

/**
 * @param string $serialized
 */
public function unserialize($serialized)
{
    list (
        $this->id,
        $this->username,
        $this->password,
        $this->enabled
        ) = $this->unserialize($serialized);
}
```

When I try to login I don't get any error whatsoever just a `ERR_EMPTY_RESPONSE`. But when I get the token from the `ContextListener::handle()` method and try to unserialize it it says that the string is wrong.

So it has to do with serializing but I don't know/understand what I do wrong...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is not enough information in your question, but i guess it's multibyte string issue there. Check your logs, in nginx/apache logs folder, or app/logs folder. Or you can try to use `json_encode/decode` functions in `serialize/unserialize`  methods instead of `serialize/unserialize` functions. Eg.:

```
public function serialize()
{
    return \json_encode([$this->id]);
}

public function unserialize($serialized)
{
    list($this->id) = \json_decode($serialized);
}
```